# How to shuffle 3 dimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I am uncertain how to deal with this situation.

I have the following 3 dimensional array:

```
$stimuli['sample'][0] = "1";

for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++){

    $stimuli['comparison'][0] = $i;
}
```

So this is how my script is setup. I want to only shuffle `$stimuli['comparison'] but not $stimuli['sample']`.

How could this be done?

Comment: what do you mean by shuffle? Do you want to randomize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `$stimuli['comparison']` is an array itself, I would "shuffle" it directly. Also, you should put something inside to test it:

```
$stimuli['sample'][0] = "1";
$stimuli['comparison'][0] = "G";
$stimuli['comparison'][1] = "H";

foreach ($stimuli['comparison'] as $arrComparison ) {
    echo $arrComparison;
}
```

With this you have:

```
G
H
```

(I'm not english native speaking so I gave my meaning to "shuffle", probably wrong, I thought you wanted to give the values inside `$stimuli['comparison']` array)

Answer (score -1):

So I found out how to shuffle it.

```
$stimuli['sample'][0] = "1";

for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++){

    $stimuli['comparison'][0] = $i;
}
shuffle $stimuli['comparison'];
```

THis works. Sorry for this, I thought it wouldn't work on the 3 dimensional array. It only work son a subfield of the array which is awesome.

Thankks anyways! Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: There is only 1 item in `$stimuli['comparison']`. Also, `parse error`.